# Writeln output extended data type as floating-point not as Scientific Expression

Tags: delphi, math

Good night, I'm having a issue with writeln on Embarcadero 10.2, I'm trying to write the sin() function as a Taylor expansion infinite serie.

Everything it's running fine, but the output is being in Scientific Expression like: 3.60448486921676E-0158 when the correct was 0.912945250727627654376099983845.

I need a 30 digits precision. My code below, It's a console program.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Windows,
  Math;

function fact(n: LongInt): extended;
begin
  if (n = 0) then
     fact := 1
  else
     fact := n * fact(n - 1);
end;

var
  one:integer;
  fin:extended;
  number:LongInt;
  i:integer;
  cons:LongInt;
  cons1:extended;
begin
  one := -1;
  writeln('Digite o angulo em radianos para o Seno: ');
  readln(number);
  for i := 1 to 120 do
  begin
    cons := (2*i)+1;
    if(i mod 2) = 0 then 
      one := 1
    else 
      one := -1;
    cons1 := fact(cons);
    fin := (one/cons1)*(power(number,cons));
    cons := 0;
  end;
  writeln(fin);
  readln;

end.
```

Comment: Delphi does not have a floating point type with 30 digits precision. See the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Simple_Types_%28Delphi%29#Real_Types)

Comment: This is a interesting topic. I also never could show extended as floating... How can I do it with like 10~15 digits? In C it's normal

Comment: For non-scientific notation, try something like `Writeln(MyExtended:30:18);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;


function sine(n: real): real;
asm
fld n
fsin
fstp Result
end;

var
n:real;
begin
write('Write the number: ');
readln(n);
writeln(sine(n):10:11);
readln;
end.
```

Comment: Pascal RTL contains `Sin` function, so why use asm? And what about 30 digits precision? ;-)

Comment: Are you aware that your code uses double and not extended variables? So you can roughly get only half of the required precision. Are you aware the x87 FPU cannot handle arguments >= 2^63? Have you ever tried to compute `sine(ldexp(1,63))` and wonder why the result is a very large number (9223372036854775810.0)?

Answer (score 3):

To perform calculation with very long precision, you need some library for arbitrary precision arithmetics - use Delphi wrapper/interface to GMP or some Delphi library. [Example](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/tag/multiple-precision/). [Another one](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/bigdecimals.html).

Note that for libraries with only long integers support (not floats) you still can calculate series like this Python code (it has internal support for big integers. `**` is power, `//` is `div`).
The only division (slow operation) is performed once.

```
d30 = 10**30
d60 = d30 * d30
x = 3141592653589793238462643383279 // 4   #Pi/4 * d30
xx = - x * x
denom = d30
nom = x
sum = nom
i = 2
while abs(nom) * d30 > denom:
    nom =  nom * xx
    mul = i * (i + 1) * d60
    denom = denom * mul
    sum = sum * mul + nom
    i += 2

print('0.' + str(d30 * sum // denom))

>> 0.707106780551955811469384356540
```

Approach is based on this:
`x - x^3/6 + x^5/120 = (x*120 - x^3 * 20 + x^5) / 120`

Comment: I edited the link to my BigIntegers to point to my BigDecimals. Probably better suited for such a task. I have already done cosines up to 10,000 digits with no problem (and checked them with online resources). Just take a few extra digits of precision (I found 5 to be more than sufficient, even for 10,000 digits) and round back to the desired precision at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Computing `sin(x)` with Taylor expansion is stable only for small arguments, say less than Pi/2. For larger arguments you suffer from catastrophic cancelation, because intermediate terms are very large, e.g. for `x=100` the largest terms is the 49'th with a value
`0.107151028812546692318354675952E43`. All these large terms are added together and give a sin() value with magnitude `<= 1`.  You would need about 70 decimal digits, do compute the result with about 30 digits.

The solutions is: Use range reduction and multiprecision floating-point routines
(see `mpf_sin` in my opensource Pascal [MPArith](http://www.wolfgang-ehrhardt.de/misc_en.html#mparith) package). Using the interactive calculator you get

`sin(100) = -0.5063656411097587936565576104597854321` in 0.2 ms.